# Cant see taken pictures after saving as file

Tags: android, android-camera, android-file

I want to take a picture and save it as a file on the sd-card. All works fine, the camera starts, the pictures were taking, and saving. If i check the picturefolder on my device, i see the taken picute, but if i check the folder from another actvity, i cant see the taken pictures. The same, if i check the folder from my pc. What is wrong with my code?

Here is my code for the Cameraactivity

```
//Init ImageView
    mPhotoCapturedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewThumbNail);

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        mPhotoCapturedImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMAGE_" + timeStamp+ "_";

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ PHOTO_ALBUM + imageFileName + ".jpg");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            //5
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The path of PHOTO_ALBUM is

```
public static final String PHOTO_ALBUM = "/MyIdea/IdeaGallery/";
```

Comment: you have to set permission or not ?

Comment: I set permissions for the camera and for write on a sd-card like 

`<uses-permission-sdk-23
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

Comment: If you are running on `Marshmallow` then you have to take Run Time Permission.

Comment: https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=590 : try this one

Comment: sure thats the problem of permissions? Cause i can see the taken files on my device in the folder.

Comment: @Saif Thans for the tutorial. I tried this. It works fine. But if i try to save the picture in my folder, i get a FileNotFoundException. Do I need to get the permission first at this moment?

Comment: @Pratik Butani, can you write me some examplecode for my issue?

Comment: first you check folder is found or not .. its not there then create the folder and put images ...

Comment: i creat a folder for the images in my startactivity. The folder exists and the images are in the folder. But i cant see them on my pc or over the android gallery

Comment: Ok, after reboot my phone, i see the pictures in the gallery. Is that an Android Bug? @Saif

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that SD-Card is scanning after mounting and show all new pictures. This simply line of code solve all my problems:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(CameraActivity.this, new String[]{file.getPath()}, new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
```

Thanks all for the help!